# Make it happy in small things: it?

Tags: meaning

I was chatting with a friend on Twitter, and I asked what the profile photo was, and he asked me to guess, and then I guessed it right. He said, "Good guess, yes, congratulations" and I replied with "lol", so he said, "Make it happy in small things.." I am not quite sure what "it" refers to here. Is it standard English? 
According to my research, it can sometimes refer to the situation or circumstances (no one can stay here - it's too dangerous now). And it can refer to "to do" like "it's dangerous to do so". However, neither fit into this context.

Comment: I don't understand the situation:  Were you chatting online or face to face?  What did you mean by "the profile picture"?   What do you mean by "fun things"?  Who was the person you were chatting to?    The quoted sentence doesn't seem to make any sense, but you haven't provided enough context to answer the question.  Is it possible that you misheard?  I don't think you are likely to get a useful answer without more details.

Comment: @JamesK It was online, and profile picture just means profile photo (for example the profile photo of my ID on this forum). Fun things are just.. fun words I guess? He was just someone I made friends with on Twitter. I didn't make sense of what he meant either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like proper English.

It's hard to answer without any context (the specific details of the "fun things" he said might be useful).

The closest I could come would be something like:

> It's the small things in life that make us happy.

(E.g., a conversation with a friend.)

Perhaps he was trying to communicate that (in which case, the "it" would be you!).

Comment: Well just something as "Good guess, yes, congratulations"... (not that funny I know) But using "it" to mean us may be a bit inappropriate (I guess?)

Comment: Perhaps he was referring then to happiness derived from his profile picture (even though it's a small thing)?

Comment: I don't think that makes sense because in that case the sentence would be "make happiness happy in small things". And since "happiness" is not mentioned anywhere in the text, maybe it's not appropriate to refer to it if it's impossible to guess?

Comment: I was thinking more of "it" referring to himself or his own happiness in an abstract way. It's an odd statement for sure! Are you still in touch with this person? Could you ask what it meant? :)

Comment: Maybe it could be "his state of happiness" like you said (although it's unclear whether he meant that from the text)?? Because I still feel it odd to use "it" to refer to a person. I will ask him although I feel that it's a bit splitting hairs (yes I am talking about myself omg)

Comment: Just curious, but may I ask why you would think "it" might refer to himself? Is it permissible to use "it" this way? :)

Comment: No, I'm really just guessing at what it *could* mean, but it's definitely not proper English.

Comment: So I guess it's not proper when meaning happiness then? But why though?

Comment: In what sense? Please explain a bit more.